# WPF GUI unresponsive updating ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, performance, user-interface

UPDATE: It looks like the two  rows in the datatemplate are what is slowing it down. If I comment just those two lines out, ie

```
<Image Source="{Binding IconSelect}" Width="20" Height="20" />
```

and

```
<Image Source="{Binding IconBaseAcctFlag}" Width="20" Height="20" />
```

It works fine. Any idea why having these images in the datatemplate freeze the GUI when the list is being rendered to the list view?

I have a form which contains two panels. On the left is a tree view and when you click on a row, it then retrieves the corresponding data for this entity and builds up a summary pane on the right, represented by a list view.

I am fetching and processing the data on a background thread and then just using Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke() on the final call that sets the ItemsSource property of the ListView to the collection I have built up. I would have expected this to maintain a very responsive GUI but at the time of updating the ItemsSource property, the GUI freezes for about 1.5 seconds while this takes place and I'm not sure why this is taking so long.

Ive also tried binding an empty ObservableCollection at the start and then invoking the dispatcher on every addition to the collection. This makes it a bit more responsive but the panel loads line by line and it is still not the performance I would like, plus the code ends up very messy with so many dispatcher calls.

Can anyone suggest what might be the issue here? Surely you can bind a generic collection with about 12-20 entries to a listview and have it update almost instantly?

```
public void DisplayAcctSummary(RbcUIAccount selAcct)
{
    if (selAcct == null)
    {
        ClearBaseAcctTransSummary();
        return;
    }

    InvokeUpdate(() => gbBaseDetails.Header = "Account Details");
    InvokeUpdate(() => lvBaseAccountDetails.ItemsSource = null);

    SelBoolValueForSelectedQueue();

    var lstBaseAcctDetails = new ObservableCollection<RbcUIBaseAcctDetails>();

    if (selCustSummary != null)
    {
        var offsetAllowed = IsOffselAllowed(selAcct.Branch);
        lstBaseAcctDetails.Add(new RbcUIBaseAcctDetails("Account No:", selAcct.AccountId));
        lstBaseAcctDetails.Add(new RbcUIBaseAcctDetails("Account Name:", selAcct.AcctDesc));
        lstBaseAcctDetails.Add(new RbcUIBaseAcctDetails("Account Type:", ((RbcEnums.AccountType)selAcct.AccountType).ToString()));

        if (selAcct.Branch != string.Empty)
        {
            var rbcBranch = RbcStaticData.GetBranchbyID(selAcct.Branch.Trim());
            lstBaseAcctDetails.Add(new RbcUIBaseAcctDetails("Branch:", rbcBranch.BranchName));
        }

        if (!IsInCURView && !IsInCURPendingView)
        {
            var serviceLayer = new RbcServiceLayer();
            var account = serviceLayer.GetAccountById(selAcct.AccountId, UserSession.SecurityContext);

            if (account != null)
            {
                if (account.BaseId != string.Empty)
                {
                    lstBaseAcctDetails.Add(new RbcUIBaseAcctDetails("Current Balance:", selAcct.CurrentBalance, false, selAcct.DisplayUSDRate));

                    if (!offsetAllowed || (IsInCCMPView) || (IsInCCMPPendingView))
                    {
                        lstBaseAcctDetails.Add(new RbcUIBaseAcctDetails("Available Balance:", selAcct.AvailableBalance, false, selAcct.DisplayUSDRate));
                        lstBaseAcctDetails.Add(new RbcUIBaseAcctDetails("Available Funds:", selAcct.AvailableFunds, false, selAcct.DisplayUSDRate));
                        lstBaseAcctDetails.Add(new RbcUIBaseAcctDetails("Base Sublimit:", rbcUtils.DisplayAmount(selAcct.BaseSublimit)));
                        lstBaseAcctDetails.Add(new RbcUIBaseAcctDetails("Available Funds SL:", selAcct.AvailableFundsSL, false, selAcct.DisplayUSDRate));
                    }

                    if (!IsInCustomerEnquiryView && !offsetAllowed)
                    {
                        var excessToday = new RbcMoney();
                        var totAwtToday = SumTotalAwtForAccount(selAcct.AccountId);
                        var totAwtAllDates = SumTotalAwtAllDatesForAccount(selAcct.AccountId);

                        excessToday.Amount = totAwtToday.Amount - selAcct.AvailableFunds.Amount;
                        excessToday.Currency = totAwtToday.Currency;

                        if (excessToday.Amount < 0)
                            excessToday.Amount = 0;

                        lstBaseAcctDetails.Add(new RbcUIBaseAcctDetails("Total Awaiting Today:", new RbcMoney(Math.Round(totAwtToday.Amount), totAwtToday.Currency), false, selAcct.DisplayUSDRate));
                        lstBaseAcctDetails.Add(new RbcUIBaseAcctDetails("Total Excess Today:", new RbcMoney(Math.Round(excessToday.Amount), excessToday.Currency), false, selAcct.DisplayUSDRate));
                        lstBaseAcctDetails.Add(new RbcUIBaseAcctDetails("Total Awaiting All Dates:", new RbcMoney(Math.Round(totAwtAllDates.Amount), totAwtAllDates.Currency), false, selAcct.DisplayUSDRate));

                        if (customer.Category != Convert.ToByte((CustCategory.Today)))
                        {
                            lstBaseAcctDetails.Add(new RbcUIBaseAcctDetails("Total Awaiting Future:", selAcct.TotalAwaitingToday, false, selAcct.DisplayUSDRate));
                            lstBaseAcctDetails.Add(new RbcUIBaseAcctDetails("Total Excess Future:", selAcct.TotalExcessToday, false, selAcct.DisplayUSDRate));
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    lstBaseAcctDetails.Add(new RbcUIBaseAcctDetails("Current Balance", selAcct.CurrentBalance, false, selAcct.DisplayUSDRate));

                    if (!offsetAllowed && account.BaseId != string.Empty)
                    {
                        lstBaseAcctDetails.Add(new RbcUIBaseAcctDetails("Available Balance:", selAcct.AvailableBalance, false, selAcct.DisplayUSDRate));
                        lstBaseAcctDetails.Add(new RbcUIBaseAcctDetails("Available Funds:", selAcct.AvailableFunds, false, selAcct.DisplayUSDRate));
                        lstBaseAcctDetails.Add(new RbcUIBaseAcctDetails("Available Funds SL:", selAcct.AvailableFundsSL, false, selAcct.DisplayUSDRate));
                    }
                }
            }

            if (IsInCCMPView || IsInCCMPPendingView)
            {
                lstBaseAcctDetails.Add(new RbcUIBaseAcctDetails(AppString.CustomerSummary.EarmarkPaymentDate, "0", true, string.Empty));
            }
        }

        if (!IsInCURView && !IsInCustomerEnquiryView)
        {
            var txnCount = 0;
            double totAmount = 0;
            RbcUITransaction transaction;

            foreach (var t in selAcct.Transactions)
            {
                transaction = t;
                var amount = rbcUtils.GetAmountInCustomerCurency(transaction.Amount.Amount, transaction.Amount.Currency, customer.CustCurrencyId);
                totAmount += amount;
                txnCount++;
            }

            lstBaseAcctDetails.Add(new RbcUIBaseAcctDetails("No of Txns:", txnCount.ToString()));
            lstBaseAcctDetails.Add(new RbcUIBaseAcctDetails("Value of Txns:", new RbcMoney(totAmount, customer.CustCurrencyId), false, true));
            lstBaseAcctDetails.Add(new RbcUIBaseAcctDetails("Last updated at:", selAcct.LastUpdatedAt.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm") + " GMT"));
        }
    }

    InvokeUpdate(() => lvBaseAccountDetails.ItemsSource = lstBaseAcctDetails);
}
```

UPDATE: Here is the XAML for the ListView

```
<ListView x:Name="lvBaseAccountDetails" Margin="10,10,10,10" Background="#F4F8FB" ItemsSource="{Binding}" MouseDoubleClick="lvBaseAccountDetails_MouseDoubleClick" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource myHeaderStyleColor}">
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView ColumnHeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource myHeaderStyle}">
                        <GridView.Columns>
                            <GridViewColumn Header=""  >
                                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate >
                                        <Grid>
                                            <Image Source="{Binding IconSelect}" Width="20" Height="20" />
                                        </Grid>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn>
                            <GridViewColumn Width="200" Header="" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding SubBaseAcctType}" >
                            </GridViewColumn>
                            <GridViewColumn Width="200" Header=""  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding SubBaseAcctValue}">
                            </GridViewColumn>
                            <GridViewColumn Header=""  >
                                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate >
                                        <Grid>
                                            <Image Source="{Binding IconBaseAcctFlag}" Width="20" Height="20" />
                                        </Grid>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn>
                        </GridView.Columns>
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>
```

Comment: I don't see any mention of the Dispatcher (or your background threading) in the code you've posted.  Can you include the rest of it, please?

Comment: Also: how complex is your Xaml datatemplate?  It is possible that there are user controls running complex code when the UI is created?

Comment: You say you're fetching the data, from a database I presume.  Are you using anything like Entity Framework or nhibernate?

Comment: Sorry, InvokeUpdate(Action a) is a helper method I have that just calls Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(a); It is only used at the end of the method above. And the entire method is being called by Task t = new Task(() =>  DisplayAcctSummary(acct)); t.Start();

Comment: Re: datatemplates, it could well be something to do with that. I changed the list being bound to a List<string> with twenty entries of "test" and it loaded almost instantly but with blank entries, so I'm guessing there's a DataTemplate mapping the RbcUIBaseAcctDetails object being added to the List above. Ill take a look

Comment: (1) Are you sure that your `Task` is in fact executing on a background thread? (2) Would it make a difference if you explicitly set a higher `DispatcherPriority` in your call to `Dispatcher.Invoke()`?

Comment: If there's any lazy loading of the images you mention as slowing everything down going on, then it's possible they're not loaded until the list is actually rendered, which could be a very substantial performance hit. It might also affect things if the images are a lot bigger than the display size, and so there's more data flying around and resize operations being done as well (although the latter should be reasonably quick).